# How functions io() and feathers() exist?

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I am new to Feathers and this could be the most dumb question I have ever asked in my entire life of developer, but I will jump in... hoping you can help me

This extract is from the quick start of [Feathers website](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/starting.html#in-the-browser)

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/@feathersjs/client@^4.3.0/dist/feathers.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Set up socket.io
  const socket = io("http://localhost:3030");

  const app = feathers();

  // Register socket.io to talk to the server
  app.configure(feathers.socketio(socket));

  // Form submission handler that sends a new message
  async function sendMessage() {
    const messageInput = document.getElementById("message-text");

    // Create a new message with the input field value
    await app.service("messages").create({
      text: messageInput.value,
    });

    messageInput.value = "";
  }

  // Renders a single message on the page
  function addMessage(message) {
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += `<p>${message.text}</p>`;
  }

  const main = async () => {
    // Find all existing messages
    const messages = await app.service("messages").find();

    // Add existing messages to the list
    messages.forEach(addMessage);

    // Add any newly created message to the list in real-time
    app.service("messages").on("created", addMessage);
  };

  main();
</script>
```

And I am wondering:

Where the functions io() from `const socket = io("http://localhost:3030");`and feathers() from `const app = feathers();` are defined ? That doesn't make an error

Comment: Without checking, they are most likely defined in the linked scripts `feathers.js` and `socket.io.js`

Comment: so they are exported from these files and they are accessible globally ? but how , because they are not imported and still we can access them ?

Comment: They most likely attach themselves to the global scope (`window` object in browsers) so that it can be easily accessed `window.io === io`. Anything that is attached to `window` can be referred to without the reference to it (this is an over-simplification but works here)

Comment: thank you that makes more sense now !

Answer (score 0):

those two functions are defined inside

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/@feathersjs/client@^4.3.0/dist/feathers.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
```

if you want to use them inside webpack project (react, vue, ...) [use proper packages](https://crow.docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#socketio-socket):

```
const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio-client');
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io('http://api.feathersjs.com');
const app = feathers();
```